How could I add a thermostat or remote control to a hardwired wall heater?
I have a wall heater very much like this one:

This is a very simple heater that's hardwired, with a simple dial to turn on the heat, and how high.
This device is in a studio that's detached from the rest of the house, and it does a very good job of heating the studio, but it can take an hour to bring the room up to temperature, during which time it's uncomfortable to work there. If I just leave it on all night, then it's too hot, and probably wastes a ton of energy.
So I'd like to retrofit either a thermostat or remote control to this thing. A thermostat would obviously let me set a minimum nighttime temperature and keep the room there until I change it. But I would also be okay with a simple remote control that just turns the whole circuit on and off, and then in the morning I could turn it on from inside the house, via remote, and then by the time the studio was needed, it would be warm enough.
How could this be done?

Assuming that the existing control is a simple thermostat, you should be able to wire a line voltage thermostat to do what you want.
First, determine if the existing thermostat is indeed truly simple. The easiest way to do that is to adjust the control so that the heat is on. Then, while the heat is on, turn off the circuit breaker. The heat should turn off (it it does not then you have the wrong breaker). If there is a fan then on/off will be immediately obvious. If there is no fan then you may need to wait a few minutes for the heater to cool down. Then turn the circuit breaker back on. If the heater starts working again (obvious if there is a fan, if not then wait a few minutes to see if it heats up) then you have a simple control and a line voltage thermostat will work. If it does not turn on again without adjusting the control then the control is more complex and a line voltage thermostat will not work here.
Next comes the wiring. It is relatively easy to install a thermostat right next to the heater. However, it is much better to have the thermostat in a more central location to avoid short-cycling and to maintain the desired temperature. The trick is going to be figuring out if there is an existing good location where you can splice into the wire. The catch is that (a) all splices must be in a junction box (if the thermostat is mounted on the box that's great but the wires may not go in the right place for that), (b) splices require a bit of extra wire and (c) installers generally don't leave much excess wire. There is also the possibility of conduit (wires inside tubes) vs. cables (wires in a non-metallic sheath, a.k.a. Romex). Which gives a few possibilities:

Existing junction box in a good location - install the thermostat there. (Least likely scenario.)
Subpanel (a detached building should have its own subpanel, if not there are big problems to deal with first) is near a reasonable location for the thermostat. Disconnect the wires from the breaker/panel. Route them to a junction box near the panel. Install a new cable (if it is wires in conduit then things get a bit more complicated) from the new box to the breaker/panel. Install the thermostat on the box.
Subpanel is not near a reasonable location for the thermostat. Things get complicated and need to discuss options.

The related question is what type of thermostat can you use. The key to figuring that out is to look at the circuit breaker. Is it a single breaker (120V) or double breaker (240V)? How many amps? (usually a number on the breaker handle)
